# Angular 2 Not working Collapse function with *ngFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angular

I am trying to add items inside sidebar menu.
Collapse function is working fine(showing subitems) when I remove the class ".collapse" from subitems, but I need to use the collapse function, of course I am getting the menu data from a JSON.

Sidebar.html

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
<li *ngFor="let item of menu">
  <a class="collapsed" data-target="#sidebar-dashboard" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar">
    <span class="icon">
        <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
      </span>
    {{ item.name }} 
     <i class="toggle fa fa-angle-down"></i>  
  </a>
  <ul id="sidebar-dashboard" class="collapse">
    <li *ngFor="let subitem of item.submenu">
      <a>{{ subitem.name }}</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Plunker link: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/0dq0NiiTtYQwK5jRUQhG?p=preview

Why collapse function is broken when I put ngFor inside of "li" and when I replace ngFor by text the collapse function works fine?

How I can solve it?
Any single help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Preferably in https://plnkr.co. Now it's very hard to figure out what's going on in your example. And it's very unlikely you'll get an answer.

Comment: **plnkr** is not functional. I'm guessing you haven't created it as Angular 2 project